# Can checksum comparison indicate how different 2 files are?

Tags: checksum

Basically like the title:

Can checksum comparison of 2 audio files indicate ***how*** different they are as well as whether they are simply different?

I need to choose one of the multiple checksum types (MD5, CRC32, SHA1) to test whether a scanned file is in fact the same as a previously scanned one. However it occurred to me that it might be feasible when comparing 2 checksums to know how similar the two files are which would be very useful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO, checksums like MD5, SHA, ... are purely hashes. Even a change in one bit typically results in completely different checksum. There is simply no correlation between how the cheksum and input changed.